# How to keep span tags and classes inside pre codeblock in TinyMce

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

I'm trying to store a piece of code using TinyMce. In the editor when I insert it it looks perfect, with tags (spans) that stylize the content. Here you have a quick example, cut to not to fill the page, of what it looks like while editing if you inspect it on DOM:

```
  <pre class="language-php" contenteditable="false">  
      <span class="token keyword">if</span> 
         <span class="token punctuation">(</span><span class="token variable">$media</span>
         <span class="token punctuation">)</span> <span class="token punctuation">{</span>        
       <span class="token punctuation">}</span>
   </pre>
```

The problem is that once I save in my SQL database the spans within `<pre>` disappear, I have checked the moment in which this happens and it is before saving in the database and processing it in php.

Then an issue of how TinyMCE processes the data, and after a google search I have been unable to find a solution to the problem.

Im using TinyMCE 5.x, without any premium plugin.

**TLDR**: Im trying to store a code snippet inside `<pre>` tags, once I insert it inside TinyMCE it looks nice (Thanks to spans with classes), and it puts spans all arroud all characters, but once I save the content, it eats all the spans inside pre.

Comment: Can you please try this code once

tinyMCE.init({   
    valid_elements : "pre"
});

valid_elemnets key will contain all those tags which you want to allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for anyone coming here with the same problem as me.

My problem was how that my understanding of how it worked was wrong, the little fella that made the syntaxis work with styles was [prismjs](https://prismjs.com/) so, the there is no answer to my question, but there is a solution for my problem.

You don't care about the spans inside your `<pre>` and `<code>` tags because if you later instantiate prismjs in the page where the content is shown it will be automatically styled as a code from the IDE.

I hope it helps someone coming here in the future that took the wrong approach to the problem as I did.